# Check if a website is alive with c#?

Tags: c#, web-applications, web

i'm new to c# and i'd like to create a tool in visual studio that can check if a website is alive or not. I found out that i have to do a head request and check if i get a 200 respond. I searched in google and here but i can't find a proper solution. The things i tried out didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated. thx?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("Site goes here");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    //Site is down
}
else
{
    //Site is up
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to just check if the webserver is responding have a look at this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/SimplePing.htm) which shows how to ping another machine otherwise use this [link](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx) for information about retrieving webpages

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsWebsiteUp(Uri uri)
{
    try
    {
        var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

HttpClient is probably the more common way to do this now.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var checkingResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (!checkingResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   return false;
}
```